# CSS3 matrix rotation flips rotation direction

Tags: css, animation, matrix, rotation

I've got a problem with rotating a simple div-container(rectangle) using the keyframe animation of css3 in firefox 26.0. The rect should rotate counter clockwise all the time, but it doesn't!

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
    div {
        position: absolute;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        background-color:red;
        border:1px solid black;
    }

    @keyframes mcTest {
        0.0%  { transform: matrix( 0.4, -0.2,  0.2,  0.4, 0, 0); } 
        40.0% { transform: matrix(-0.8, -0.1,  0.1, -0.8, 0, 0); } 
        60.0% { transform: matrix(-0.9,  0.1, -0.1, -0.9, 0, 0); } 
        100.0%{ transform: matrix( 1.0,  0.2, -0.2,  1.0, 0, 0); } 
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="animation: 5s linear 0s normal none infinite mcTest;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The abnormal behaviour occurs between 40% and 60%, when the sign of the 2. and 3. matrix-parameter (x-skew and y-skew) changes. I've recognized, that this behaviour depends on the 1. parameter. It must be near -0.85 to make the problem appear.

Any help or hints will be appreciated! :)

Comment: Please check my updated code I think i give you which you are looking for.

Comment: I've found an expensive workaround for this bug. You have to minimize the animation time of the 2. matrix parameter at the point where it changes from negative to positive. E.g. a small step from 50.0% to 50.00001%. so you won't see the wrong animation part ...